# Why is rem behaving like an em with this code?

Tags: html, css

Why is rem behaving like an em with this code?

```
<div style="font-size: 10px; height: 5rem">test</div>
```

My html root font-size is 16px and this div is the only element in my html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length#rem):

> `rem`
>   This unit represents the font-size of the root element (e.g. the font-size of the  element).

If the `html` will have `font-size: 16px`, the `5rem` height of your `div` element will be `5*16=80px`.

You can see the height of `80px` in the following snippet:

```css
html {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div style="font-size: 10px; height: 5rem; border: 1px solid red;">test</div>
```

> Note that the font-size will not change. It will be `10px`; Only the `height` of your `div` will change.

Answer (score 1):

The `height` attribute is the height of the box, not the font of the text.

Changing the font size of the div doesn't affect its strictly set height.

See, I'm setting the different font size and the height doesn't change - to show that, I've picked the red background.

```css
html {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div style="font-size: 10px; height: 5rem; background: red">test</div><br>
<div style="font-size: 40px; height: 5rem; background: red">test</div><br>
<div style="font-size: 100px; height: 5rem; background: red">test</div>
```